# Excel formula to returning "Good" when all boxes are equal error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have created a formula that returns 'good' in column S if all of the fields in the formula are the same ie. all return 'True' except only one of K or L has to be true or false. However when a field is blank such as the first cell in column O it is still giving a "good" in Col S however it should give a "" as it is not equal to True. Any idea where I am going wrong? Or how I can go about this problem better?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=IF((K1+L1)*(SUMPRODUCT(--N1:R1)=COLUMNS(N1:R1))>0,"Good","")
```

[image]

Comment: Clear and precise answer.

Comment: How difficult would it be to add an extra validation that would return "good" if all were false aswell even if there is a blank in 'O'? For example in the first row of your example. For example, a "" in the check should be FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,"",TRUE,TRUE.

Comment: `=IF((K1+L1)*((SUMPRODUCT(--N1:R1)=COLUMNS(N1:R1))+(SUMPRODUCT(--N1:R1)=0))>0,"Good","")`